# Dynamic attribute binding with Viewmodel

Tags: meteor, viewmodel

I have a simple `button` component in my Blaze templates. I want it to accept attributes to apply to the resulting element alongside other things, but as I've found out, you can't do it the same way as in other bindings: `<button {{b "attrs: getAttrs"}}>{{text}}</button>`, where `getAttrs()` returns the desired attributes from arguments doesn't work, as the binding argument is taken literally, i. e. it ends up taken as an object with keys `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7` (the string `'getAttrs'` keys), and attempting to set attributes with those names, resulting in a DOM exception. What can be done in my case?